# I am trying to find the closure of the sets 1) $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: xy < 1\}$ and 2) $\{(x,y): x,y \in \mathbb{Q}, x^2+y^2 <1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to find the closure of the sets 1) $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: xy < 1\}$ and 2) $\{(x,y): x,y \in \mathbb{Q}, x^2+y^2 <1\}$. I know that for 1) the set is open but I don't know what that means for the closure of the set.

Answer (score 1):

Note the second set is not open

1) $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | xy \leq 1\}$ and 2) $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2| x^2+y^2 \leq1\}$

$B$ is the closure of $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ means $\forall x\in B$, you can find a sequence of $\{x_n\}\in A$ s.t. $x_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$. Try to verify the above two sets are indeed the closure of your sets using this criterion.

Comment: That is the definition for finding a closed set yes. So would I have to graph the xy <1 and x^2+y^2 < 1 and find points inside of that?

Comment: @jbebe44 What you need to do is actually find the smallest closed set containing the original set. But for $\mathbb{R}^2$, personally I think it's easier to use sequential criterion I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: for 1) would it just be union [1,-infinity]? or would it be more like union R